# How can I keep a Signed-In User's data through the navigation of other pages after a session has been created? HTML-Express JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, session

This month I've been trying to implement a webpage that consists of different functions. While I'm keen with **HTML** and **JavaScript**, it's my first contact with **Node JS** and **MongoDB** technologies.

At first I have a **Users** Database in MongoDB with info like username,password etc. In my **Sign-In** page I have implemented the log-in function correctly and logs the user if the credentials match. Now with that, I wanted the creation of a **Session** when the user logs in and it's end when he logs out. I also did that corrrectly using express-session.

**!** The thing that I can't figure out, is how I can keep the user's data through the whole alive status of a Session while browsing other pages of my navigation bar.

Here is my **Sign In** route that works

```
router.use(session({
secret: 'your-secret-key', // Replace with your own secret key
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true

},  
));

router.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
const { username, password } = req.body;

try {
 const user = await User.findOne({ username: username, password: password });
 if (user) {
  // User found, authentication successful
  req.session.user = user; // Save the user object in the session

  // Display verification message in the terminal
  console.log('User signed in:', user);
  if (user.trait === 'User') {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Authentication successful', redirect: 'user_home.html', userData: user });
  } else if (user.trait === 'Admin') {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Authentication successful', redirect: 'admin_home.html', userData: user });
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Authentication successful', redirect: 'home.html', userData: user });
  }
} else {
  // No user found, authentication failed
  res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password' });
} } catch (err) {
res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
```

}
});

Basically when the Sign-In button is pressed depending on the user's trait "Admin" or
"User" he gets redirected to a specific home page and a Session is created. The user's info is saved to a session variable **req.session.user** and the console displays it.

**Problem**: When I try to insert the same console log line to the other pages and navigate so I can verify that the user's data is kept, I get errors, **Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined** . I also tried to create a Welcome "Username" ! message that appears on the header but the name doesn't get displayed either. The only time the user's info is displayed in terminal is when the Log-In happens.

From I can tell, the user data is stored only when the sign-in is successful. Isn't a session variable able to keep storage of the data throughout the whole alive status though? In overall, my Session creation works fine but I've been troubleshooting with different ways like LocalStorage too and found no solution at maintaining the user's info. Btw my app.js is correct and I've set the mandatory libraries of express-js + my paths are all correct.